# Update multiple in one query in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem on how can I update multiple in mysql in just one query the flow here is just like these.

*This will work and runs correctly*

```
UPDATE table SET date_1 = Null WHERE '0000-00-00' = DATE_FORMAT(table_column1,'%Y-%m-%d')
UPDATE table SET date_2 = Null WHERE '0000-00-00' = DATE_FORMAT(table_column2,'%Y-%m-%d')
UPDATE table SET date_3 = Null WHERE '0000-00-00' = DATE_FORMAT(table_column3,'%Y-%m-%d')
```

> What I've tried

```
UPDATE table SET date1= NULL, date2= NULL, date3= NULL WHERE '0000-00-00' = 
DATE_FORMAT(table_column1,'%Y-%m-%d') OR '0000-00-00' = DATE_FORMAT(table_column2,'%Y-%m-%d') OR
'0000-00-00' = DATE_FORMAT(table_column3,'%Y-%m-%d')
```

*But the problem, it update all of my records into null even if the value of each column is not equal to `0000-00-00` since I've been using `OR` statement. It would be great if anybody could figure out, thank you so much in advance!.*

Comment: What datatype is date1,date2,date3 ?

Comment: @P.Salmon thanks for your response it is `date` datatype

Comment: @Strawberry thanks for your response I just want to changed the date format in database like this `2021-10-10`

Comment: Why DATE_FORMAT()? If the columns table_columnX are timestamps or datetimes then DATE() will do.

Comment: _“it update all of my records into null even if the value of each column is not equal to 0000-00-00 since I've been using OR statement”_ - well, yeah, of course. Before, you had three _separate_ UPDATE statements, that each only update one specific column, based on a condition tied to that same specific column. But now, you are updating all three columns in one go. You either select a record to be updated with your conditions, or you don’t. You can’t switch to AND either, because that would only update records that had all three fields `0000-00-00` at the same time. […]

Comment: […] So you would have to work with conditionals here - set each field to NULL when it satisfies your condition, set it to its old value that it already has otherwise: `… SET date_1 = IF(…, Null, date_1), …`

Comment: In the first example, the columns are named `date_1` etc but in the second example (your attempt), they are called `date1` (without the underscore)? Is it a typo in the question or is it a real typo in your code as well?

Comment: However, problems of this type are highly suggestive of poor schema design

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
UPDATE table SET date_1 = CASE WHEN '0000-00-00' = DATE_FORMAT(table_column1,'%Y-%m-%d')
                               THEN NULL
                               ELSE date_1 END, 
                 date_2 = CASE WHEN '0000-00-00' = DATE_FORMAT(table_column2,'%Y-%m-%d')
                               THEN NULL
                               ELSE date_2 END, 
                 date_3 = CASE WHEN '0000-00-00' = DATE_FORMAT(table_column3,'%Y-%m-%d')
                               THEN NULL
                               ELSE date_3 END;
```

PS. WHERE conditions are copied as-is.

PPS. I recommend to add WHERE clause which ensures that at least one column from table_columnX ones contains zero date also.

Comment: The question has moved on a bit in comments, rendering much of the above superfluous

Comment: @Strawberry I do not see the question edition. Moreover, I do not see a comment words which makes my answer incorrect. Please be more specific.